# Why a dynamic dependent drop down fails to load when embedded in Google Site

Tags: google-apps-script, dynamic, drop-down-menu, google-drive-api, google-sites

Why a dynamic dependent dropdown based on a JSON file in G-Drive fails to load when embedded G-Site? The authorization for the embedded web app is given to anyone with G-Account.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll("select");
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
});
document.getElementById("nativeState").addEventListener("change", getDistr);

function getDistr() {
    var state = document.getElementById("nativeState").value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updatedistricts).getDistricts(state);
}

function updatedistricts(distrList) {
    nativeDistr.innerHTML = distrList;
    var subcatSelectElem = document.querySelectorAll("select");
    var subcatSelectInstance = M.FormSelect.init(subcatSelectElem, {});
}
```

The code of the function used to render the page within IFrame.

```
function render(file, argsObject) {
var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(file);

if (argsObject) {
    var keys = Object.keys(argsObject); // key can be like a stateList from tmp.stateList
    keys.forEach(function (key) {
        tmp[key] = argsObject[key];
    });
} //End If

var updateTmp = tmp.evaluate().addMetaTag("viewport", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1");
//return tmp.evaluate();
//To embed code in site using XFrame
return updateTmp.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
```

}

> The App is deployed with URL ending with /exec.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: When you go to Publish->Deploy As WebApp... what are the settings there? Also, does your url end in "dev" or "exec"? It should be exec for other users.

Comment: @Stykes My URL ends with exec, not as a dev.

Comment: @Cooper I acknowledge your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with access to execution. The expected value is USER_DEPLOYING rather than a user accessing the web app.

> "webapp": {
>       "access": "ANYONE_ANONYMOUS",
>       "executeAs": "**USER_DEPLOYING**"
>     }